# Why can Find-Package not find a package by name on my local package source

Tags: powershell, package-managers, powershellget

I have a local package source to mess around with some things. I created a brain-dead package called `CoolUtils`, adding it using `nuget add`. You can find it using nuget:

```
PS> nuget list -source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\
CoolUtils 2.0.20171024.1

PS> nuget list coolutils -source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\
CoolUtils 2.0.20171024.1
```

However, `Find-Package` can't find it by name, but can find it with wildcards or no name specified:

```
PS> Find-Package -Source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\

Name                           Version          Source                           Summary
----                           -------          ------                           -------
CoolUtils                      2.0.20171024.1   E:\nuget-repo-test-01\           Test package with dumb scripts.

PS> Find-Package *cool* -Source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\

Name                           Version          Source                           Summary
----                           -------          ------                           -------
CoolUtils                      2.0.20171024.1   E:\nuget-repo-test-01\           Test package with dumb scripts.

PS> Find-Package CoolUtils -Source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\
Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'CoolUtils'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Find-Package CoolUtils -Source E:\nuget-repo-test-01\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ets.FindPackage:FindPackage) [Find-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.FindPackage
```

I also can't install it using `Install-Package`, though I can using `nuget`.

Answer (score 5):

Cmdlet `Find-Package` is part of **PackageManagement** module, while `Nuget.exe` is one of a dozen of *package providers* for `PackageManagement` module.

An analogy (not fully correct) is an application and plugins:   `Nuget` is like one of plug-ins which provides functionality to its application (`Find-Package`, `Install-Package` and other cmdlets from PackageManagement).

Despite `Nuget` can do *some* package management tasks, in order to work under control of standardized `PackageManagement` commands you should properly declare ("register") nuget's package locations to make them known for `PackageManagement`:

`Register-PackageSource -name MyPackages -location E:\nuget-repo-test-01 -provider Nuget`

---

Now `Find-Package` can search and `Install-Package` can install packages from newly registered *package source*. Full list of known package sources can be retrieved by

`Get-PackageSource`

Comment: I have done this, and Find-Package is finding my package when I'm using no name or `-Contains mypkg`, but not when I'm using `-Name`. I think it must be specific to the NuGet Provider. When I try the same thing using the PSGallery source (PowerShellGet provider), it works for `Name`, and it spits a no-such-parameter for `Contains`..
The chocolatey provider supports both `Name` and `Contains`...

Comment: @PaulHicks That means that search capabilities are delegated to Package providers and this is up to them which search tools they are going to provide to the client

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and managed to solve it by moving the .nupkg file to the root of the registered local package source, i.e. "C:\projects\packages\"

```
PS> Get-PackageSource -Name Local

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
Local                            NuGet            False      C:\projects\packages\

PS> Find-Package -Source Local -Name TestCmdlet

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
TestCmdlet                     1.0.0            Local            Package Description
```